# Match string and extract outside element?

Tags: dom, xpath, domxpath

Sample:

```
<div class="luikang">
    <p>Lui Kang information:<br><br>

        <strong>First game:</strong> Mortal Kombat (1992)<br>
        <strong>Created by:</strong> John Tobias<br>
        <strong>Orgin:</strong> Earthrealm<br>
        <strong>Weapon:</strong> Nunchaku<br>
        <strong>Colour:</strong> Red</p>
</div>
```

I would like to extract `Nunchaku`

My try so far:

```
/html/body//div[@class='luikang']/p/strong[contains(., 'Weapon:')]
```

I am guessing I need to use this too:

```
[count(preceding-sibling::br) < 1]
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: How the hell did you manage to write "Liu Kang" incorrectly :D

Comment: Oh, I don't have a good answer too that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `/html/body//div[@class='short_description']/p/strong[contains(., 'Weapon:')]/following-sibling::text()[1]`.